# Getting notification when app is killed(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, background

I am developing a food delivery app. This project has two apps:

1. User app - which helps the customers to order
2. Admin app - which helps the hotel owners to view the order

(I am not using firebase as a backend)

I encountered a problem with notification. The admin app has to trigger notification as soon as the order is placed by the user(using User app). To solve this I have tried various plugins like background_fetch, android_alarm_manager, Flutter Workmanager etc. But these plugins have a minimum frequency of 15 minutes. Is there any plugins/way to trigger notification(even when the app is killed) when the order is placed?. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid these 15 minutes minimum frequency. I think You should check push notifications with Firebase in your project.